# Joomla 1.5 one install - multiple virtual hosts: can I unite logins?

Tags: authentication, joomla1.5, virtual-hosts

I've set up multiple virtual hosts that all lead to the same Joomla 1.5 installation (e.g. *host1*.mysite.com, *host2*.mysite.com, etc).

Seems that when a user logins to one of the virtual hosts then moves to another he needs to re-login.
The cookies/sessions are saved for each host separately.

Is there anyway that I can unite the logins? (i.e. save the session / send the cookie for mysite.com, regardless of subdomain?)

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could only be done by modifying the Joomla source code. There's a similar question here:
[can-you-set-a-cookie-only-for-domain-tld-and-www-domain-tld](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975666/can-you-set-a-cookie-only-for-domain-tld-and-www-domain-tld)

So you would need to modify Joomla so that it gives cookies out for your 'mysite.com' domain, rather than what the installs will be doing now, which is giving out cookies for 'host1.mysite.com', 'host2.mysite.com', etc.